# Image loading order in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which by default is a button. But when pressed, it is replaced by four other buttons, each of which has a PNG image.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import styles from './CallButton.module.css'
import whatsAppImg from '../../images/whatsapp.png'
import telegramImg from '../../images/telegram.png'

const CallButton = () => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    return (<div className={styles.container}>
        {isActive ?
            <div className={styles.appearsLeft}>
                <a className={styles.callButton} title={'Написать в WhatsApp'} href="https://wa.me/+79147726787">
                    <img src={whatsAppImg} className={styles.icon}/>
                </a>
                <a className={styles.callButton} title={'Написать в Telegram'} href="https://t.me/yolkin27">
                    <img src={telegramImg} className={styles.icon}/>
                </a>
            </div> :
            <div className={styles.main}
                 onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>
                <div className={styles.notActiveButton}>Связаться со мной</div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>);
};

export default CallButton;
```

In idle state it looks like this:

[image]

And in active state:

[image]

But the fact is that the pictures in the buttons start loading only after the transition to the active state. And I would like them to be loaded in advance. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the images loading by calling `Image` constructor at the moment of component mounting.

Your code should look like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import styles from './CallButton.module.css'
import whatsAppImg from '../../images/whatsapp.png'
import telegramImg from '../../images/telegram.png'

const imagesSrcs = [whatsAppImg, telegramImg];

const CallButton = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    imagesSrcs.forEach(imageSrc => {
      (new Image()).src = image;
    })
  }, []);

  return (<div className={styles.container}>
    {isActive ?
      <div className={styles.appearsLeft}>
        <a className={styles.callButton} title={'Написать в WhatsApp'} href="https://wa.me/+79147726787">
          <img src={whatsAppImg} className={styles.icon}/>
        </a>
        <a className={styles.callButton} title={'Написать в Telegram'} href="https://t.me/yolkin27">
          <img src={telegramImg} className={styles.icon}/>
        </a>
      </div> :
      <div className={styles.main}
           onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>
        <div className={styles.notActiveButton}>Связаться со мной</div>
      </div>
    }
  </div>);
};

export default CallButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the images code to a variable, and rendering the variable conditionally, should get you the result you're after.

i.e:

```
let socialImages = (<div className={styles.appearsLeft}>...);
```

Then:

```
{isActive ? socialImages : <div>...</div>}
```